# Sort a matrix according to only one column

Tags: matlab, sorting

I have this matrix A,

```
A= [10  -12  4  8;
    1  3  11 -2;
    1  -9  8  0;
    1  1  9  3].
```

if I use the sortrows function in Matlab `B = sortrows(A)`. I will get this.

```
B = [1    -9     8     0;
     1     1     9     3;
     1     3    11    -2;
     10   -12     4     8].
```

The answer I wanted is this.

```
B = [1   3     11     -2; 
     1  -9  8      0;
     1   1  9      3;
    10   -12     4     8]
```

The thing is, I want to sort my rows here but only based on column 1. if values in column 1 are same, then don't sort them according to column 2(which in genreal this function perform).

I really appreciate, if anyone can help me with this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sort the first column only with the function `sort` keep only the index, then use this index to sort the whole matrix.

```
A= [10  -12  4  8;
    1  3  11 -2;
    1  -9  8  0;
    1  1  9  3];
[~,ind] = sort(A(:,1))
B = A(ind,:)
```

or simply use the second argument of the function `sortrows` which precise the column sorting vector:

```
B = sortrows(A,1)
```

Comment: Hello, @Obchardon, Thank you so much, It'sworking, really appreciate your effort. Thank you :)